# Can't get fglrx to work

Tags: 12.10, fglrx

I tried switching to fglrx from the Additional Drivers tab in Software Sources. Though when I restarted my system, all that displayed was my wallpaper and the courser. I managed to switch back to the X.org driver.

I thought fglrx was fixed in Ubuntu 12.10. When will it be fixed again? I have had these problems before.

Comment: I didn't have any problem with fglrx until I upgraded to the latest kernel. I am running 12.10 and I end up with this box that says: "safe mode" if I am correct. I cant even log in. Removed fglrx and restored xorg and but the laptop is overheating because of xorg

Comment: Yeah, similar problem. Do you know when it will be fixed again?

Comment: No clue at all :-s

Comment: ok, I solved it by installing `linux-headers-generic` Hope this will work for you too. and Uninstall `fglrx driver` just to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by installing linux-headers-generic and then re-installing the driver.